# Cartesian product subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given a set X = {$\varnothing$, {a, b}, {a} }, what is Cartesian product of X $\times$ X ?

I think X $\times$ X should be {$\varnothing$, ({a,b},{a,b}) , ({a,b},{a}) , ({a},{a,b}) ,({a},{a}) }.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: $\varnothing $ is always assumed to be part of every set, and any pair with one element $\varnothing$ is assumed to be $\varnothing$

Comment: You need $(\emptyset, \{a,b\} )$, etc.

Comment: Also, $\emptyset \notin X \times X$.

Comment: (∅,{a,b}) = $\varnothing$, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product: A = {1,2}; B =  $\varnothing$;
A $\times$ B = {1,2} $\times$  $\varnothing$ =  $\varnothing$

Comment: Matt, it is true that $\emptyset \times A = \emptyset$, but that is not what you have above. There is a difference between the empty set and a set containing a single element (which happens to be the empty set). That is, $\emptyset \neq \{ \emptyset \}$. I can't find the statement $(\emptyset, \{ a,b \}) = \emptyset$ on the Wiki page (it would be incorrect if it was)?

Comment: @copper.hat, the answer is {$\varnothing$, X $\times$  X, {(a, a)}, {(a, a), (a, b)}, {(a, a), (b, a)}, {(a, a), (a, b), (b, a)} }. I think the answer is odd because every element is a set, not a tuple. the answer is from  http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4522/Lectures/L15.html

Comment: Matt, you are confusing the topology with the cartesian product. The product topology is not the same as the product. In the example given in the reference you mentioned, $X = \{a,b\}$. It is **always** the case that if $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, then $|A \times B| = mn$.

Answer (score 3):

I nave another point of view unlike Shobhit: $X$ consists of $3$ elements, independently of their nature. So $|X\times X|=9$.

Answer (score 2):

The empty set is just another element.

If $X=\{ u,v,w \}$, then $X \times X = \{ (u,u), (u,v), (u,w), (v,u), ... \}$.

So, if $X=\{ \emptyset, \{ a,b\}, \{a\} \}$, then $X \times X = \{ (\emptyset,\emptyset), (\emptyset,\{ a,b\}), (\emptyset,\{a\}), (\{ a,b\},\emptyset), ... \}$.